# Accessing SAFE ARRAY data in a VARIANT

Tags: arrays, automation, tags

I use a function in my code that returns a `VARIANT` data type and in this `VARIANT` there is a `SAFE ARRAY` of my equipment.

> How I can access this `SAFE ARRAY`?

```
 VARIANT namList; 
 SAFEARRAY* myequip;
 namList=str->GetNames();
```

I want to extract this `SAFE ARRAY` from `namList` and use `SafeArrayGetElement()` to access my equipment information.